# Express.js req.body parametr array

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, express, routes

I have problem with my routes where I want check some data from req.body form

I have route

```
  app.post(`/${randomQuestionsArray[0].id}`, (req, res) => {
const reqValue = req.body.answer;
console.log(reqValue);
console.log(randomQuestionsArray[0].reqValue);
```

}),

Fragment of data:

```
const jsonContent = {
  "questions": [
      {
          "id": "1",
          'slug': "566fghg6",
          "title": "post title 1",
          "desc": "This is a test desc 1",
          "answer1": {
              "answer": "test1",
              "value": true
          },
           "answer2": {
              "answer": "test2",
              "value": false
          },
           "answer3": {
              "answer": "test3",
              "value": false
          },
           "answer4": {
              "answer": "test4",
              "value": false
          }
      },
```

req.body.answer - give me value of form etc answer1 
But I want to take some data from array 
I create variable:

`const reqValue = req.body.answer; 
randomQuestionsArray[0].reqValue give me undefined`  
but if I write by hand:
randomQuestionsArray[0].answer1 give me data 
 "answer": "test1",
 "value": true

How I can put req.body to my array params?

Comment: Use `randomQuestionsArray[0][reqValue]` instead of `randomQuestionsArray[0].reqValue` if using hardcoded value works for you.

Comment: Thx for help. It is working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use regular POST method you may address this in the following manner

Let's say you post to "/datalogger"

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/datalogger", function (req, res) {
    var strTitle = req.body.slug
    console.log("The title: " + strSearch);
    res.end("ok");
});
```